# How to print leading zeros (padding) in awk?

Tags: awk, string, text-formatting

I am trying to print `99.11111` as `099.11` in `AWK`.

I have tried the following variations without success.

```
$ awk '{printf ("%000.2f\n", $1);}' <<< 99.111111
99.11
$ awk '{printf ("%3.2f\n", $1);}' <<< 99.111111
99.11
$ awk '{printf ("%03.2f\n", $1);}' <<< 99.111111
99.11
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{printf("%06.2f\n", $1)}' <<< 99.111111
099.11
```

The padding length takes  into account the whole formatted number, so with the fractional part taking up 3 characters (`.` and the `2` precision digits), you need a padding length of 6 if you want the integral part to be padded to a length of 3. Note that the padding also takes into account the sign if any so `-1` for instance would be formatted as `-01.00`¹

---

<sup>¹ or possibly `-01,00` or `-01٫00` depending on the user's locale and the `awk` implementation². In the case of GNU `awk`, it also depends on whether there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment or not.</sup>

Comment: Without awk: `LANG=C printf "%06.2f\n" 99.111111`

Comment: @GillesQuénot :I'd just add the warning that, in bash, an integer value (or real when cast to integer) starting with 0 is considered an octal  by bash: `f() { echo $(( i + 1 )) ;}`, then `f 003` shows 4, `f 003.12` rightly complains about the ".12" part, but `f 008`complains that 008 doesn't fit the base (base8 as 008 starts with a 0), and `f 008.12` also complains about that (before it could complain about the 0.12 part). Additionnaly: `f 003` give 4 without surprise but `f 011` gives 10, as 011 octal is 9.